# Asymptotics of $\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {k^n}{k!}\right)^\frac1n$ at $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Solving  [the problem on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-value-of-lim_-n-to-infty-frac-ln-n-n-sqrt-n-sum_-k-1-infty-frac-k-n-k), I tried also to get a reasonable approximation of $$ (S_n)^\frac1n=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {k^n}{k!}\right)^\frac1n\,\text{at}\,n\to\infty$$
Using Laplace method (which, frankly speaking, is not formally applicable in this case), I got
$$(S_n)^\frac1n\sim \frac {n\,e^{\frac1{W(n)}}}{e\,W(n)}$$
where $W(n)$ is Lambert function. The approximation works rather well - in spite of arbitrary usage of the method:
$\displaystyle n=100 \quad\frac{\ln n}n\left(S_n\right)^\frac1n\bigg|_{n=100}=0.667365...\,;\quad \frac {\ln n\,\,e^{\frac1{W(n)}}}{e\,W(n)}\bigg|_{n=100}=0.672337...$

$\displaystyle n=1000 \quad\frac{\ln n}n\left(S_n\right)^\frac1n\bigg|_{n=1000}=0.585123...\,;\quad \frac {\ln n\,\,e^{\frac1{W(n)}}}{e\,W(n)}\bigg|_{n=1000}=0.585692...$

etc.

My question is whether we can prove the result in a rigorous way, or provide a more accurate and justified asymptotic, using some other evaluation technics?

---

*Follow up*

The asymptotic of Bell numbers solves the problem;
@Command Master and @Cactus - thank you for the information. One of the ways of evaluation (by means of complex integration) can be found [in this pape](https://oeis.org/A000110/a000110_4.pdf). It is interesting to note that the correct first term of the asymptotics can be obtained in one line by simply applying the Laplace method. I got
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {k^n}{k!}=\frac1{\sqrt{W(n)+1}}\left(\frac {n\,e^{\frac1{W(n)}}}{e\,W(n)}\right)^n$$
what coincides with the first term of the asymptotics in the paper. The formula in Wikipedia is not quite accurate (contains $\frac1{\sqrt{W(n)}}$ instead of $\frac1{\sqrt{W(n)+1}}$).

The formula gives good approximation already for small $n\sim 10$.

Comment: You can use Dobinski's formula and the known asymptotic growth rate of the Bell numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can simplify you equivalent. Indeed, $W(n) \rightarrow +\infty$ thus $e^{1/W(n)} \sim 1$ and $W(n) \sim \ln(n)$ thus $\frac{ne^{1/W(n)}}{eW(n)} \sim \frac{n}{e\ln(n)}$.

Then, as @Command Master suggested it, you can use the Dobinski formula,
$$
B_n = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k \geqslant 0} \frac{k^n}{k!},
$$
where the $(B_n)$ are the Bell numbers (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), which verify,
$$
B_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}\right)^{n + 1/2}\exp\left(\frac{n}{W(n)} - n - 1\right).
$$
Therefore,
$$
S_n^{1/n} = (eB_n)^{1/n} \sim \frac{1}{n^{1/(2n)}}\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}\right)^{1 + 1/(2n)}\exp\left(\frac{1}{W(n)} - 1\right) \sim \frac{n}{e\ln(n)}.
$$
Notice that $u_n \sim v_n > 0$ for $n$ large enough implies $u_n^{1/n} \sim v_n^{1/n}$ but the reciprocal is false in general, so having an equivalent on $S_n$ (given by the equivalent of Bell's numbers) is much more powerful than having an equivalent on $S_n^{1/n}$.

Comment: Right, I corrected it. I don't know how we get the asymptotic, it seems pretty hard, I'll try to find an other way to prove the equivalent of $S_n^{1/n}$ (which is easier).